# How to create a yocto recipe to compile and install an application using CMake?

Tags: cmake, yocto, recipe

I'm trying to compile an application for an embedded linux target board (STM32mp157) and I have a problem when I try to compile and install an application directly into my image.

I use the release `Kirkstone` of Yocto and I have created a recipe to fetch my source code and my `CMakeLists.txt` file from a github repository. I use the inherited cmake as it is noted in the yocto documentation (https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev/dev-manual/new-recipe.html).

> ***CMake:*** If your source files have a `CMakeLists.txt` file, then your software is built using CMake. If this is the case, you just need to modify the configuration.
>
> When you use CMake, your recipe needs to inherit the [cmake](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev/ref-manual/classes.html#ref-classes-cmake) class and it does not have to contain a [do_configure](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev/ref-manual/tasks.html#ref-tasks-configure) task. You can make some adjustments by setting [EXTRA_OECMAKE](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev/ref-manual/variables.html#term-EXTRA_OECMAKE) to pass any needed configure options that are specific to the recipe.

I have installed my yocto SDK on my host PC(Ubuntu 20.04) and I cross-compiled my app using my generated tool-chain. The cross-compiled application runs fine but when I try to compile and install the same source code application directly on my image the application binary differs in size and it creates many runtime errors that end up exiting the application.

File `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.3)

project(myapp)

set(Source_Files
"src/main.c"
"src/custom_app.c"
"src/custom_app.h"
)

set(ALL_FILES ${Source_Files})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${ALL_FILES})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} 
        modbus
        sqlite3
        iothub_client
        aziotsharedutil
        umqtt
        pthread
        curl
        m
        json-c
        parson
        gpiod
        )

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
```

and my recipe .bb

```
SUMMARY = "Myapp"
DESCRIPTION = "Myapp"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

DEPENDS = "azure-c-shared-utility azure-iot-sdk-c json-c libmodbus sqlite3 libgpiod parson"

SRC_URI = "\
    git://github.com/username/myapprepo.git;branch=main;protocol=ssh \
"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

inherit pkgconfig cmake systemd


RDEPENDS:${PN} = "azure-c-shared-utility azure-iot-sdk-c azure-macro-utils-c azure-umqtt-c python3-azure-iot-device"

BBCLASSEXTEND = "native nativesdk"
```

I tried debugging my application from within my target board, checking the different logs created by my build system's recipe but I still can't get to turn around this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: What runtime errors?  If you try with a simple application (hello world) does it work?  If your recipe ran without error, then I'd expect it's not an issue with cmake.

Comment: hello! I keep getting seg-fault errors i do not see when I crosscompile and debug my application. If I use it for a simple application it does work. Thing is, the binary is different as well ($ size myappsbinary) outputs a different size in text and data, as in the crosscompiled binary.

Comment: The size being different probably doesn't matter and could be the result of lots of things  (e.g., different compilation flags, libraries changing, etc.).  If the simple application works then the recipe is likely fine and you'll need to debug your application.  If you're not already, try to use the SDK generated from yocto (I forget the command to generate this, it's been a while) if you're not already.  You should be able to get debug symbols from the yocto build and debug that directly as well.